# LicenseInformation.IsActive is false

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

i am developing a Windows RT app that will work on (x86, x64 and ARM) CPUs. The app has a trial mode so when i check if the app is in trial mode or not at startup MSDN recommends using this if block

```
public static LicenseInformation LicenseInfo = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation;
if (LicenseInfo.IsActive)
{ //.... } else {// What does it mean if it is false???}
```

So what doesn't mean if the "APP license" is not active? does it mean the app is no longer in the store or what ?

Thank you all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MSDN page on the [`LicenseInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.licenseinformation.aspx) Class. This [**page**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp.licenseinformation.aspx) also states that it reads the application Metadata and does not require a network connection

From above link

> For app trial versions of an app, IsActive will return true so long as the trial hasn’t expired.
>   During the trial period the IsTrial returns true, 
>   returning false when the customer upgrades to the full version of the app.

Comment: So what will happen if i try to check the trial mode and there is no internet connection with the store? will the app crash, throw an exception or just continue normally?

Comment: Everything that I read says that it will continue normally, It is just reading the application Metadata, you will have to publish it initially to the Store though.